# Convert csv.DictReader object to non-iter type data and merge values by keys

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, python-itertools, ordereddictionary

In my data:

```
myData='''pos\tidx1\tval1\tidx2\tval2
11\t4\tC\t6\tA
15\t4\tA\t6\tT
23\t4\tT\t6\tT
28\t4\tA\t3\tG
34\t4\tG\t3\tC
41\t4\tC\t4\tT
51\t4\tC\t4\tC'''
```

I read the this data with header as keys, csv.DictReader.

```
import csv
import itertools

input_file = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(myData), delimiter = '\t')
# which produces an iterator

''' Now, I want to group this dictionary by idx2, where
idx2 values is the main key and other have values merged into list that have same keys'''

# This groupby method give me
file_blocks = itertools.groupby(input_file, key=lambda x: x['idx2'])

# I can print this as
for index, blocks in file_blocks:
    print(index, list(blocks))

6 [{'val2': 'A', 'val1': 'C', 'idx1': '4', 'pos': '11', 'idx2': '6'}, {'val2': 'T', 'val1': 'A', 'idx1': '4', 'pos': '15', 'idx2': '6'}, {'val2': 'T', 'val1': 'T', 'idx1': '4', 'pos': '23', 'idx2': '6'}]
3 [{'val2': 'G', 'val1': 'A', 'idx1': '4', 'pos': '28', 'idx2': '3'}, {'val2': 'C', 'val1': 'G', 'idx1': '4', 'pos': '34', 'idx2': '3'}]
4 [{'val2': 'T', 'val1': 'C', 'idx1': '4', 'pos': '41', 'idx2': '4'}, {'val2': 'C', 'val1': 'C', 'idx1': '4', 'pos': '51', 'idx2': '4'}]

But, since the output is exhausted I can't print, use it more than once to debug it.
```

So, 
problem #1: how to I convert it into non iter-type data.

Problem #2: how can I process this groupby object further to merge the values to a list that have common keys within same group/blocks.

```
Something like orderedDict, defaultDict where the order of the way the data is read is preserved:

{'6': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'pos': [11, 15, 23], 'idx1': [4, 4, 4], 'val1': ['C', 'A', 'T'], 'idx2': [6, 6, 6], 'val2': ['A', 'T', 'T']})}
{'3': .....
{'4': .....
```

### Some of the fixes I tried:

I rather thought I could prepare a keys:[values] by unique keys before grouping:

```
update_dict = {}
for lines in input_file:
print(type(lines))
for k, v in lines:
    update_dict['idx2'] = lines[k,v]
```

Other thing I tried was to se if I can merge the data inside the grouped object:
    new_groupBy = {}
    for index, blocks in file_blocks:
        print(index, list(blocks))
            for x in blocks:
                for k, v in x:
                do something for new_groupBy

Comment: "But, since the output is exhausted I can't print, use it more than once to debug it." ... did you try putting it into some container, like a `list` instead of printing?

Comment: @sKwa: Oops! Typo fixed now.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I have tried doing that. But, I am not able give it a fix. Also, any downstream analyses is just keeping it as an iterator. Any suggestions.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? It looks like you seem to understand how to iterate over a group-by iterator, so, can't you just populate a with the results?

Comment: "how to I convert it into non iter-type data" cast is to `list()` to preserve the contents of the iterator.

Comment: do you know how generators works and what is it _lazy initialization_?

Comment: @sKwa There are no generators here...

Comment: I just started learning about generators and iterators, but I can't seem to work the fix. I have tried using list() to print the output. But, how do I save it as another object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yeap you are right, but it works in the same way.

Comment: @everestial007 it sounds like you need to go to Python basics. `list` doesn't print things, it turns an iterable into a list object. You can assign the result to a variable if you want to keep it around

Comment: Since results are grouped by `"idx2"`, do you really want this entry repeated in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as for your first problem, you can simply materialize a list:

```
In [9]: raw_data='''pos\tidx1\tval1\tidx2\tval2
    ...: 11\t4\tC\t6\tA
    ...: 15\t4\tA\t6\tT
    ...: 23\t4\tT\t6\tT
    ...: 28\t4\tA\t3\tG
    ...: 34\t4\tG\t3\tC
    ...: 41\t4\tC\t4\tT
    ...: 51\t4\tC\t4\tC'''

In [10]: data_stream = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(raw_data), delimiter="\t")

In [11]: grouped = itertools.groupby(data_stream, key=lambda x:x['idx2'])

In [12]: data = [(k,list(g)) for k,g in grouped] # order is important, so use a list

In [13]: data
Out[13]:
[('6',
  [{'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '6', 'pos': '11', 'val1': 'C', 'val2': 'A'},
   {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '6', 'pos': '15', 'val1': 'A', 'val2': 'T'},
   {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '6', 'pos': '23', 'val1': 'T', 'val2': 'T'}]),
 ('3',
  [{'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '3', 'pos': '28', 'val1': 'A', 'val2': 'G'},
   {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '3', 'pos': '34', 'val1': 'G', 'val2': 'C'}]),
 ('4',
  [{'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '4', 'pos': '41', 'val1': 'C', 'val2': 'T'},
   {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '4', 'pos': '51', 'val1': 'C', 'val2': 'C'}])]
```

As for your second problem, try something like:

```
In [15]: import collections

In [16]: def accumulate(data):
    ...:     acc = collections.OrderedDict()
    ...:     for d in data:
    ...:         for k,v in d.items():
    ...:             acc.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
    ...:     return acc
    ...:

In [17]: grouped_data = {k:accumulate(d) for k,d in data}

In [18]: grouped_data
Out[18]:
{'3': OrderedDict([('pos', ['28', '34']),
              ('idx2', ['3', '3']),
              ('val2', ['G', 'C']),
              ('val1', ['A', 'G']),
              ('idx1', ['4', '4'])]),
 '4': OrderedDict([('pos', ['41', '51']),
              ('idx2', ['4', '4']),
              ('val2', ['T', 'C']),
              ('val1', ['C', 'C']),
              ('idx1', ['4', '4'])]),
 '6': OrderedDict([('pos', ['11', '15', '23']),
              ('idx2', ['6', '6', '6']),
              ('val2', ['A', 'T', 'T']),
              ('val1', ['C', 'A', 'T']),
              ('idx1', ['4', '4', '4'])])}
```

Note, I used list (and dict) comprehensions. They are work similarly. The list comprehension is equivalent to:

```
data = []
for k, g in grouped:
    data.append((k, list(g))
```

And for good measure, here's the equivalent to a dict-comprehension, although I'm using an OrderedDict, since in any case, order seems to be important:

```
In [20]: grouped_data = collections.OrderedDict()

In [21]: for k, d in data:
    ...:     grouped_data[k] = accumulate(d)
    ...:

In [22]: grouped_data
Out[22]:
OrderedDict([('6',
              OrderedDict([('val2', ['A', 'T', 'T']),
                           ('val1', ['C', 'A', 'T']),
                           ('pos', ['11', '15', '23']),
                           ('idx2', ['6', '6', '6']),
                           ('idx1', ['4', '4', '4'])])),
             ('3',
              OrderedDict([('val2', ['G', 'C']),
                           ('val1', ['A', 'G']),
                           ('pos', ['28', '34']),
                           ('idx2', ['3', '3']),
                           ('idx1', ['4', '4'])])),
             ('4',
              OrderedDict([('val2', ['T', 'C']),
                           ('val1', ['C', 'C']),
                           ('pos', ['41', '51']),
                           ('idx2', ['4', '4']),
                           ('idx1', ['4', '4'])]))])
```

Note, we can do everything in a single pass, avoiding creating unnecessary data-structures:

```
import itertools, io, csv, collections

data_stream = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(raw_data), delimiter="\t")
grouped = itertools.groupby(data_stream, key=lambda x:x['idx2'])

def accumulate(data):
    acc = collections.OrderedDict()
    for d in data:
        for k,v in d.items():
            acc.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
    return acc

grouped_data = collections.OrderedDict()
for k, g in grouped:
    grouped_data[k] = accumulate(g)
```

Comment: thanks @juanpa. I was now trying to access the data (grouped_data) in a forloop. `for x, y in grouped_data:
    print(x)` But i get this error message `for x, y in grouped_data:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: @everestial007 You are asking how to iterate over a dictionary (`OrderedDict` objects *are* `dict` objects) see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: Now, from the whole ordered dict, I am trying to access nested `OrderedDict` and the `keys:values` for further processing.

Comment: @everestial007 they are *dictionaries*. Consider `grouped_data['6']['pos']`

Comment: That worked but I don't seem to understand the output. `for k, v in grouped_data['6']['pos']:
    print(k)` outputs: 1
1
2. I don't see what is is outputting.

Comment: @everestial007 look, I'm not trying to be mean, but do you understand how dictionaries work? I'm pretty sure that expression will error out. `grouped_data['6']['pos']` returns a *list* that is from index `'6'` and is the grouped `'pos'` fields...

Comment: I only briefly understand how dictionary work. What you have done just flew over my head. I will try to comprehend it. But, I don't seem to where is that `1 1 2` coming from. There is no such values in index '6'. Anyway it's fine.

Comment: @everestial007 try `print(grouped_data['6'])` then try `print(grouped_data['6']['pos']`

Comment: @pylang: Thanks for being nice. Well, I got that this time. Also, i realized that I can iterate over using `for k, v in grouped_data.items():
    print(k, v)`

Answer (score 1):

**Given**

```
import io
import csv
import itertools as it
import collections as ct    

data="""pos\tidx1\tval1\tidx2\tval2
11\t4\tC\t6\tA
15\t4\tA\t6\tT
23\t4\tT\t6\tT
28\t4\tA\t3\tG
34\t4\tG\t3\tC
41\t4\tC\t4\tT
51\t4\tC\t4\tC"""
```

*Part I*

> how to I convert it into non iter-type data

**Code**

Here's how to retain data from the iterators - simply cast it to a list:

```
>>> input_file = list(csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(data), delimiter = "\t"))
>>> input_file
[{'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '6', 'pos': '11', 'val1': 'C', 'val2': 'A'},
 {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '6', 'pos': '15', 'val1': 'A', 'val2': 'T'},
 {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '6', 'pos': '23', 'val1': 'T', 'val2': 'T'},
 {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '3', 'pos': '28', 'val1': 'A', 'val2': 'G'},
 {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '3', 'pos': '34', 'val1': 'G', 'val2': 'C'},
 {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '4', 'pos': '41', 'val1': 'C', 'val2': 'T'},
 {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '4', 'pos': '51', 'val1': 'C', 'val2': 'C'}]
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
>>> file_blocks = [(k, list(g)) for k, g in it.groupby(input_file, key=lambda x: x["idx2"])]
>>> file_blocks
[('6',
  [{'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '6', 'pos': '11', 'val1': 'C', 'val2': 'A'},
   {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '6', 'pos': '15', 'val1': 'A', 'val2': 'T'},
   {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '6', 'pos': '23', 'val1': 'T', 'val2': 'T'}]),
 ('3',
  [{'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '3', 'pos': '28', 'val1': 'A', 'val2': 'G'},
   {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '3', 'pos': '34', 'val1': 'G', 'val2': 'C'}]),
 ('4',
  [{'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '4', 'pos': '41', 'val1': 'C', 'val2': 'T'},
   {'idx1': '4', 'idx2': '4', 'pos': '51', 'val1': 'C', 'val2': 'C'}])]
```

Now you can reuse data from `input_file` and `file_blocks`.

---

*Part II*

> how can I process this groupby object further to merge the values to a list that have common keys within same group/blocks...
>
> Something like orderedDict, defaultDict where the order of the way the data is read is preserved

```
def collate_data(data):
    """Yield an OrderedDict of merged dictionaries from `data`."""
    for idx, item in data:
        results = ct.OrderedDict()
        dd = ct.defaultdict(list)
        for dict_ in item:
            for k, v in dict_.items():
                dd[k].append(v)
        results[idx] = dd
        yield results
    

list(collate_data(file_blocks))
```

Output

```
[OrderedDict([('6',
               defaultdict(list,
                           {'idx1': ['4', '4', '4'],
                            'idx2': ['6', '6', '6'],
                            'pos': ['11', '15', '23'],
                            'val1': ['C', 'A', 'T'],
                            'val2': ['A', 'T', 'T']}))]),
 OrderedDict([('3',
               defaultdict(list,
                           {'idx1': ['4', '4'],
                            'idx2': ['3', '3'],
                            'pos': ['28', '34'],
                            'val1': ['A', 'G'],
                            'val2': ['G', 'C']}))]),
 OrderedDict([('4',
               defaultdict(list,
                           {'idx1': ['4', '4'],
                            'idx2': ['4', '4'],
                            'pos': ['41', '51'],
                            'val1': ['C', 'C'],
                            'val2': ['T', 'C']}))])]
```

The order of the `itertools.groupby()` elements is maintained by a `collections.OrderedDict()`.  The order of values across the lines of the file (see the dicts in `input_file`) is preserved by the list inside the `collections.defaultdict()` object.

Comment: *nitpick: these aren't generators.

Comment: I debated using the term iterator, but perhaps you are right.

Comment: Don't believe me? `import types; print(isinstance(input_file, types.GeneratorType))`

Comment: I don't doubt you.  Good catch.  Thanks.

Comment: I understand it's incredibly pedantic, but ever since the introduction of coroutines, generators have become much more than mere handy ways of writing iterators.

Comment: Iron sharpens iron.  I appreciate the review.